# GMail push API - 400 failedPrecondition

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, elixir, gmail-api

I am trying to execute a `watch` to enable GMail push API to send notifications to PubSub. I am using Elixir, and I am already using others Google API, in the same language; for some reason, I fail with GMail API.

I am receiving a 400 BAD REQUEST, with "preconditionFailed" in the body.

Since the 400, I guessed that I was passing the value in the wrong way. So I tried to get the list of the messages, which is a call that takes no parameters:

```
{:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://mail.google.com/")
conn = GoogleApi.Gmail.V1.Connection.new(token.token)
GoogleApi.Gmail.V1.Api.Users.gmail_users_messages_list(conn, "me")
```

And still I receive a 400:

```
{:error,
 %Tesla.Env{
   __client__: %Tesla.Client{
     adapter: nil,
     fun: nil,
     post: [],
     pre: [
       {Tesla.Middleware.Headers, :call,
        [
          [
            {"authorization",
             "Bearer TOKEN HERE"}
          ]
        ]}
     ]
   },
   __module__: GoogleApi.Gmail.V1.Connection,
   body: "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"failedPrecondition\",\n    \"message\": \"Bad Request\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 400,\n  \"message\": \"Bad Request\"\n }\n}\n",
   headers: [
     {"cache-control", "private, max-age=0"},
     {"date", "Fri, 01 May 2020 19:40:10 GMT"},
     {"accept-ranges", "none"},
     {"server", "GSE"},
     {"vary", "X-Origin"},
     {"content-length", "179"},
     {"content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
     {"expires", "Fri, 01 May 2020 19:40:10 GMT"},
     {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"},
     {"x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"},
     {"content-security-policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'"},
     {"x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"},
     {"alt-svc",
      "h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""}
   ],
   method: :get,
   opts: [],
   query: [],
   status: 400,
   url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages"
 }}
```

I don't understand why this is failing. Also, I have checked with REST specs, and it looks correct:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

P.s.: as a reference, the following code works:

```
  {:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
  conn = GoogleApi.PubSub.V1.Connection.new(token.token)

  pubsub_message = %GoogleApi.PubSub.V1.Model.PubsubMessage{
    data: message |> Jason.encode!() |> Base.encode64(padding: true)
  }

  request = %GoogleApi.PubSub.V1.Model.PublishRequest{
    messages: [pubsub_message]
  }

  Projects.pubsub_projects_topics_publish(
    conn,
    <PROJECT>,
    "consolidation-messages",
    body: request
  )
```

So the authentication procedure looks correct.

Comment: You are trying to use a service account instead of OAuth user credentials. Unless you have enabled G Suite Domain Wide Delegation, service account credentials will not work with Gmail.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thanks for the reply. I _think_ that SDWD is a viable option, I can ask. Once I have enabled it, do you think should be everything in place ? Or should I deal with roles/permissions ? Why wasn't this mentioned in the official doc (or maybe it was and I did not spot it) ? Thanks !

Comment: You will need to read the documentation for Domain Wide Delegation and understand this feature. This feature provides admin rights to the G Suite member (user) accounts including impersonation. This feature is not part of Gmail, it is a G Suite / GCP feature and is part of the documentation. Note: this feature supports G Suite accounts and not Gmail (only) accounts.

Comment: Yeah I know it exists but I have never used it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, I was reading everything again, and I have one more question. Why am I receiving a 400 BAD REQUEST, and not a 401 or 403, maybe ? This is the only doubt I have, at this point.

Comment: I am not sure. Error 400 means Bad Request and can include errors where the server perceives the request to be a client error, for example (guessing), using a service account OAuth token instead of a User OAuth token. The error that you received is `failedPrecondition` which also indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API, does require impersonation to get a user's messages and other API resources.
Your G Suite Admin should delegate domain wide authority to yous service account for it to be able to impersonate the user whose messages your app wants to access.

Here is some information about Service Account Domain Wide Delegation.

- [Differences between a service account and a user account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#differences_between_a_service_account_and_a_user_account)
- [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
- [Using OAuth2 for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

---

#### Note:

There is a little part in the documentation that most people miss, and it is the key. And I'm sure it is where you are having trouble authorizing the client.

The **Addendum** here: [1]. You may have to create your own JWT token to make authorized API calls.

[1]https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

Comment: Hey @Aerials, thanks for the message. I have done everything it takes (had a personal GSuite account that I have used to try) but still I am having 400.

    {:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://mail.google.com")
    conn = GoogleApi.Gmail.V1.Connection.new(token.token)
    GoogleApi.Gmail.V1.Api.Users.gmail_users_messages_list(conn, EMAIL)

I used a specific email and `"me"`, which should be working as well. Same result.

Comment: Bruno, read the Addendum carefully, I was able to make authorized API calls on behalf of a user by creating the JWT token from the service account credentials. Give it a shot! Good luck.

Comment: I managed to make this work. I was missing a bunch of things. The service account must have enabled domain-wide authority delegation, and the topic you want to be used to the publish the message must grant publish permission to the user `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`. The important thing, when the token is generated (or the connection created, in Elixir api), is to implement impersonification: 
    
{:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://mail.google.com", EMAIL)

I think that this does, at a lower level, what you are talking about.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm talking about. It would not work if you don't use impersonation, and for that you need DWD.

Comment: Hey, update here ! Incredibly, I have everything deployed production, where I suppose the default appengine service account is used. So, I have replicated the setup (which mainly is about enabling domain-wide authority delegation) on the default account, but I cannot neither watch nor fetch history/mails.

Comment: I have fixed these problems; but I see lots of inconsistencies in the stuff I obtain when I fetch mails from historyId.